Get data from APi and set in spinner using volley in android, java
API Response: "[{"ROLEID":3,"ROLECODE":"BC","ROLENAME":"Branch Checker","ISACTIVE":1},{"ROLEID":4,"ROLECODE":"BM","ROLENAME":"Branch Maker","ISACTIVE":1}]"
But getting error.  and not giving proper response.
    HashMap<String, String> httpParams = new HashMap<>();
    NetworkRequestModel networkRequestModel = new NetworkRequestModel(UserRegister.this);
    networkRequestModel.method = Request.Method.GET;
    networkRequestModel.url = url_getBranchCode;
    networkRequestModel.requesthashMap = httpParams;
    networkRequestModel.showloader = true;
    networkRequestModel.cancelable = true;
    networkRequestModel.loaderMessage = "Wait while loading..";

    Networking.callApi(networkRequestModel, new ResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                String resp= response.replace("\\","");

               // String Resp= response.replace("\\","");
                Log.d("Response", "Response: " + resp);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                System.out.println("Yogeshkkkk" +jsonArray);

                branchList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Priyankakkk" +jsonArray.length());

                    JSONObject branchObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    int branchId= branchObj.getInt("BRANCHID");
                    String branchName = branchObj.getString("BRANCHNAME");

                    branchList.add(new BranchList(branchId,branchName));
                }

                // Log branches
                for (BranchList branch : branchList) {
                    Log.d("Branch", "ID: " + branch.getBranchid() + ", Name: " + branch.getBranchName());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                System.out.println("Yogeshkkkk" +e.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(UserRegister.this, "Error parsing JSON: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
            @Override
        public void onFailure(String errormessage) {

            Toast.makeText(UserRegister.this, errormessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

tried hard coding the API response. was able to get the response. While getting through network its not working.

Show us the error message?

string cannot be converted to jsonarray

"tried hard coding the API response. was able to get the response. While getting through network its not working." Well, I'd debug the app and see what's different in response.

As the error is "string cannot be converted to jsonarray" you might actually receive some error instead of the JSON array.
